# How to sort records by their order in the backend on a Bolt CMS listing template

Tags: sorting, content-management-system, bolt-cms

In Bolt CMS, you can re-order records in the backend (/bolt) by drag-and-drop. I assume this gets saved internally as an index value somewhere.

I have a custom template for the listing page of a particular contenttype and I want to modify it so that the listings appear in the same order that they are in the backend. However, I can't seem to find a property that mirrors that ordering, only things like `datepublished` and `datecreated`.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ordering by drag'n'drop" in the backend is a feature that's not finished yet. You should use the 'sortorder' field to manually give it a sorting order, when editing the pages. 
We'll add this feature in an upcoming version.